# Il faut lui ou celui comme antécédent d'un relatif prépositionnel?

Tags: syntaxe, pronoms-relatifs, démonstratifs

Par exemple, quelle phrase est plus naturelle?

1. C'est mon fils, **lui** avec qui tu as parlé.
2. C'est mon fils, **celui** avec qui tu as parlé.

De plus, est-ce que le fait d'être un référent animé ou non change quelle phrase est plus naturelle? Par exemple:

3. C'est mon ordinateur, **lui** avec lequel tu as tapé le message.
4. C'est mon ordinateur, **celui** avec lequel tu as tapé le message.

Mon idée, c'est que les phrases (2) et (4) sont plus naturelles, mais je n'en suis pas sûr.

Comment: _Celui_ dans tous les cas.

Comment: 1 et 3 ne sont pas juste moins naturelles, elles sont incorrectes.

Answer (score 1):

***Celui*** dans tous les cas. ([Frank](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53977/il-faut-lui-ou-celui-comme-ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent-dun-relatif-pr%C3%A9positionnel#comment115012_53977))

***1*** et ***3*** ne sont pas juste moins naturelles, elles sont incorrectes. ([Teleporting Goat](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53977/il-faut-lui-ou-celui-comme-ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent-dun-relatif-pr%C3%A9positionnel#comment115013_53977))

Answer (score 1):

Même si on choisit très majoritairement "***celui***" (plus naturel). Utiliser "***lui***" n'a rien d'incorrect grammaticalement, "***lui***" pouvant être remplacé par "***mon fils***". ([Graffito](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53977/il-faut-lui-ou-celui-comme-ant%C3%A9c%C3%A9dent-dun-relatif-pr%C3%A9positionnel/53979#comment115016_53979))

Comment: J'ai beau tourner et retourner les phrases avec _lui_ dans ma tête, j'ai beaucoup de mal à me convaincre que ce _très majoritairement_ n'est pas un _toujours_. Et j'ai essayé en imaginant de multiples scénarios, mais ça ne passe pas.

Comment: @Frank : Je n'ai pas de souci avec des phrases comme "*C'est bien ton oncle Sebastien, lui que tu croyais mort*" ou "*Soupçonner Estelle ! Elle à qui l'on donnerait le bon dieu sans confession !*".

Comment: @Graffito Moi non plus. Personne n'aura je pense de souci avec ces deux dernières phrases. Il n'en est pas de même avec *C'est bien ton ancien téléphone, lui avec lequel tu m'as appelé* ou *C'est mon prof d'espagnol, lui que je préfère.*

Comment: @Graffito En soutien de jiliagre, ce n'est pas la même chose. Ton deuxième example utilise deux phrases, alors qu'il me semble que la question porte sur une seule phrase avec deux propositions. Dans _C'est bien ton oncle Sebastien, lui que tu croyais mort_, _celui_et _lui_ sont à mon avis tous les deux possibles, avec une nuance: dans le cas de _celui_, on essaie de préciser de quel oncle il s'agit, ce qui n'est pas le cas si l'on utilise _lui_.